# Calculation of tensor structure

Tags: vector, tensors

I would like to calculate following type of contraction:

> $$
> P_{ij}^{p-k} P_{mn}^{k} ((p_l - k_l) \delta_{ij} + k_j \delta_{il}) (k_n \delta_{lm} - p_m\delta_{ln}) = ?
> $$
>   where p,k are d-dimensional vectors and 
>   $$
> P_{ij}^{k} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{k_ik_j}{k^2}, \quad P_{ij}^{p-k} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{(p_i-k_i)(p_j-k_j)}{(p-k)^2}
> $$
>   are projection operators.

First I tried to define projector operators as a function of vector variable k

```
P[k_] = 1 - TensorProduct[k, k]/k.k
```

but I cannot figure out how to define a vector function.

Is this even a good idea or is there a better way how to deal with this?

Comment: I think you are better off implementing your own tensor quantities. I.e. sc /: sc[{a_}, {b_}] sc[t_, {a_}] := sc[t, {b}]; so that for example sc[{i},{j}]sc[p,j] will evaluate to sc[p,i]. Btw these projectors look familiar, are you doing some conformal stuff?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thank you! But no, I am working with stochastic field theory. I am trying to solve tensor structures which appears when you write down field theoretical formulation for navier-stokes equations and try to study its critical dynamics (loop corrections, renormalization, RG)

Comment: Your expression in the tensor above has a misplaced index somewhere — the index $i$ appears three times.  If you correct this, I can probably write up some code that will do some of what you want.

Comment: In the corrected version, the index $l$ appears three times, so it's still not a valid tensor contraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few suggestions, but I'm not sure about their efficiency. I'm sure that if this is the only thing that you want to compute my suggestion is good enough.

What I do when I have to compute something like this is to use a lot of replacement rules and a dot product. First, define

`P[k_,i_,j_]:=delta[i,j] - k[i] k[j]/k^2`

For the P[p-k,i,j] term just use a replacement rule (one of many):

`P[p - k, i, j]//. {(a_ - b_)[c_] -> a[c] - b[c]}`

gives you the desired output.

Now you only need to use replacement rules, for example

`k[i] delta[i,j]-> k[j]`

is achieved with
rule={p_[a_] delta[a_, b_] -> p[b]}

for k^2
`rule2={p_[i_] p_[i_]->p^2}`

The dimension of your system

`rule3={delta[i_,i_]->Dim}`

You have to make sure to add all the replacement, I just added a few, you need also the case

`k[i] delta[j,i]-> k[j]`

but now you know how. Finally, you can either keep the use of 
`k[i] p[i]`
or define a dot product

`k[i] p[i]->dot[p,k]`

I go for the second, always. If you follow my advise, define P as

`P[k_,i_,j_]:=delta[i,j] dot[k,k] - k[i] k[j]`

now, when you face your expression, keep in mind that you have to divide for (k^2 (k-p)^2). Why do I use the dot? Because (p-k)^2 is not p^2+k^2-2pk. Mathematica will take
`p[i]p[i] k[j]k[j]`
to be the same as
`p[i]k[i] p[j] k[j]`
which is wrong. Now it is easier to simplify.

Saludos!